# Crash with black screen, except a dashed line on the left edge

Tags: linux, laptop, crash, intel-graphics, visual-artifacts

Recently my laptop (ASUS X54C) has started crashing once every day or two. I can't work out any proximate cause of the crash, as it often happens when I'm just reading something, and it doesn't seem excessively hot. The following is a list of precisely what I observe:

- The monitor goes black apart from the following artefacts:

  - One pixel's width on the left-hand edge, which is filled with a coloured dashed line, usually red, with the dashes each being about 16 pixels long.
  - About 100 pixels starting at the top left and continuing right along the top edge, usually coloured cyan. This can sometimes be 2 pixels high, but is usually 1 pixel high.
- When a second monitor is connected via HDMI, it shows similar patterns, but with some extra fuzziness stretching out from the left-hand edge.
- Applications don't seem to respond to keystrokes.
- REISUB does not work.
- Music stops playing immediately.
- Sometimes the fan starts spinning heavily.
- Sometimes pulling out the power cable or attaching an external monitor cause the laptop to power down, but usually not.
- The only input that seems to do anything is holding the power button for 5 seconds, which causes the laptop to power down.

I have reseated the RAM plug-in and run memtest86+, which I let clock up 9 passes and 0 errors. I usually run (and have only observed crashes on) GNU/Linux, specifically NixOS unstable with Linux 5.10.36 x86_64. The laptop is about 7 years old, but has had a replacement motherboard (3 years old) and a replacement screen (4 years old). The only peripheral other than the external monitor is a USB mouse. Most crashes have occurred without the external monitor.

Here is the output of `lspci`, which may give some useful hardware information:

```
$ lspci                                                                                                                                                                 ~
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

I have a few photos of what the crash looks like with two monitors:

[image: Both monitors]
[image: Built-in monitor]
[image: External monitor]

Comment: "run memtest86+, which I let clock up 9 passes and 0 errors."  <-- So it does not appear to be memory. Remove the extra monitor and test again. Most likely power supply or motherboard at this point.

Comment: I'll edit to add: most crashes are without the external monitor.

Comment: Then it is likely a hardware as I have noted above.

Comment: Had similar issues on multiple occasions. The most common reason so far is file system errors. FSCK might help. Run S.M.A.R.T. check to see if your HDD is dying.